# how to extract weekends and bank holidays for stock price data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
markowitz = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/jordan/Desktop/book2.xlsx')
markowitz = markowitz.set_index('Dates')
markowitz
```

[there are some NaN values in the data,some of them are weekends and some of them are holidays,i have to identify the holidays and set it as previous value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2QR5.png)

is there a simple way i can do this ,i used

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar as calendar

dr = pd.date_range(start='2013-01-01', end='2018-06-12')
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Date'] = dr

cal = calendar()
holidays = cal.holidays(start=dr.min(), end=dr.max())

df['Holiday'] = df['Date'].isin(holidays)
print (df)
df = df[df['Holiday'] == True]
df
```

but there are still a lot of dates i have to copy and paste(can i just display the second row "date")and then set them as previous trading day value, is there a simpler way to do this ? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a simpler way, if I know what you are trying to do. The fillna method on dataframes lets you forward fill. So if you don't want to fill weekend days but want to fill all other nas (i.e. holidays), you can just exclude Saturdays and Sundays as follows:

```
df.loc[~df['Date'].dt.weekday_name.isin(['Saturday','Sunday'])] = df.loc[~df['Date'].dt.weekday_name.isin(['Saturday','Sunday'])].fillna(method='ffill')
```

You can use this on the whole dataframe or on particular columns.

Comment: thank u very much . however do i have to import any thing to support this "Date"?

Comment: oh no I was just using your df['Date'] column above. df.Date is the same as df['Date'] , you can access any column (whose name doesn't have spaces) using the dot notation. I edited my answer for clarity

Comment: thank u very much. the 'df' dataframe is the one i created to identify the holidays. the frame that contains the NaN values is 'markowitz' . is there a way that i could identify and set values in 'markowitz' straight away? sorry for so many questions .......

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to get an API key from quandl.com.  It's free and it gives you access to all kinds of time series historical data.  There used to be access to Yahoo Finance and Google Finance, but I think both were depreciated well over 1 year ago.

Here is a small sample of code that can definitely help you.

```
import quandl
quandl.ApiConfig.api_key = 'your_api_key_goes_here'

# get the table for daily stock prices and,
# filter the table for selected tickers, columns within a time range
# set paginate to True because Quandl limits tables API to 10,000 rows per call

data = quandl.get_table('WIKI/PRICES', ticker = ['AAPL', 'MSFT', 'WMT'], 
                        qopts = { 'columns': ['ticker', 'date', 'adj_close'] }, 
                        date = { 'gte': '2015-12-31', 'lte': '2016-12-31' }, 
                        paginate=True)
print(data)
```

Check the link below for info about how to get the data you need.

https://blog.quandl.com/api-for-stock-data

Also, please see this for more details about using Python for quantitative finance.

https://financetrain.com/best-python-librariespackages-finance-financial-data-scientists/

Finally, and I apologize if this is a little off topic, but I think it may be helpful at some level...consider something like this...

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = 'http://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=152&s=ta_topgainers&o=price&c=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,25,63,64,65,66,67'
html = requests.get(base_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content, "html.parser")
main_div = soup.find('div', attrs = {'id':'screener-content'})

light_rows = main_div.find_all('tr', class_="table-light-row-cp")
dark_rows = main_div.find_all('tr', class_="table-dark-row-cp")

data = []
for rows_set in (light_rows, dark_rows):
    for row in rows_set:
        row_data = []
        for cell in row.find_all('td'):
            val = cell.a.get_text()
            row_data.append(val)
        data.append(row_data)

#   sort rows to maintain original order
data.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[0]))

import pandas
pandas.DataFrame(data).to_csv("AAA.csv", header=False)
```

It's not time series data, but rather fundamental data.  I haven't spent a lot of time on that site, but maybe you can poke around and find something there that suits your needs.  Just a thought.